# Changing the line style in d3js for every segment?

Tags: d3.js, svg, charts, burndowncharts

I'm trying to visualise the "additional work" resulting from change request in a burn chart. I managed to draw the chart, but I like to have the vertical lines that show the increase to have their own colour. Something like this:

[image: Burnchart]

My data is like this:

```
   var actualRaw = [{
        date: new Date(2017, 1, 1),
        added: 0,
        done: 50
    }, {
        date: new Date(2017, 1, 15),
        added: 10,
        done: 40
    }]
```

which I transform like this:

```
    var actual = [];

    actualRaw.map(line => {
        actual.push({
            date: line.date,
            points: line.done,
            class: 'la'
        });
        actual.push({
            date: line.date,
            points: line.done + line.added,
            class: 'ln'
        });

    })
```

and then try to apply formatting like this:

```
    chart.append("path")
        .datum(actual)
        .attr("class", function(d, i) {
            return 'line ' + d[i].class;
        })
        .attr("d", actualLine);
```

However that function gets called only once. What do I miss?

My [attempt so far](https://gist.github.com/Stwissel/6eddd33d44dd8c4d24baeba7501c07b2) complete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply put: you can't style different segments of a SVG `<path>` element like that.

There are alternatives, though. Here, for instance, I'm simply adding a key/value pair in `actual`...

```
actualRaw.map(line => {
    actual.push({
        date: line.date,
        points: line.done,
        class: 'la'
    });
    actual.push({
        date: line.date,
        points: line.done + line.added,
        class: 'ln',
        added: line.added//this one here...
    });
})
```

... and using it to draw simple lines (that is, SVG `<line>` elements):

```
var redLines = chart.selectAll(null)
    .data(actual.filter(function(d) {
        return d.added
    }))
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("x1", function(d) {
        return x(d.date)
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
        return x(d.date)
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return y(d.points)
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return y(d.points - d.added)
    })
    .style("stroke", "red");
```

Here is the code with those changes:

```html
<head>
  <title>Burn baby burn</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .chart {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .chart div {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
      background-color: steelblue;
      text-align: right;
      padding: 3px;
      margin: 1px;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .chart rect {
      stroke: white;
      fill: steelblue;
    }
    
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    
    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
    
    .line.ideal {
      stroke: steelblue;
    }
    
    .la {
      fill: none;
      stroke-width: 2px;
      stroke: green;
    }
    
    .ln {
      fill: none;
      stroke: red;
      stroke-width: 4px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Burn Chart</h1>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    var x = d3.scaleTime()
      .range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([height, 0]);
    var ideal = [{
      date: new Date(2017, 1, 1),
      points: 50
    }, {
      date: new Date(2017, 12, 31),
      points: 0
    }];
    var actualRaw = [{
      date: new Date(2017, 1, 1),
      added: 0,
      done: 50
    }, {
      date: new Date(2017, 1, 15),
      added: 10,
      done: 40
    }, {
      date: new Date(2017, 2, 1),
      added: 0,
      done: 40
    }, {
      date: new Date(2017, 3, 1),
      added: 20,
      done: 30
    }, {
      date: new Date(2017, 4, 1),
      added: 10,
      done: 20
    }, {
      date: new Date(2017, 5, 1),
      added: 5,
      done: 10
    }, {
      date: new Date(2017, 6, 1),
      added: 0,
      done: 10
    }, {
      date: new Date(2017, 7, 1),
      added: 5,
      done: 10
    }, {
      date: new Date(2017, 8, 1),
      added: 0,
      done: 10
    }, {
      date: new Date(2017, 9, 1),
      added: 20,
      done: 20
    }, {
      date: new Date(2017, 10, 1),
      added: 0,
      done: 10
    }, {
      date: new Date(2017, 11, 1),
      added: 5,
      done: 10
    }, {
      date: new Date(2017, 12, 1),
      added: 0,
      done: 0
    }];
    var actual = [];
    actualRaw.map(line => {
      actual.push({
        date: line.date,
        points: line.done,
        class: 'la'
      });
      actual.push({
        date: line.date,
        points: line.done + line.added,
        class: 'ln',
        added: line.added
      });
    })
    var idealLine = d3.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.points);
      });
    var actualLine = d3.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.points);
      });
    x.domain(d3.extent(ideal, function(d) {
      return d.date;
    }));
    y.domain(d3.extent(actual, function(d) {
      return d.points;
    }));
    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
      .scale(x)
      .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b %d"));
    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
      .scale(y);
    var chart = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("class", "chart")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    // Create the x-axis
    chart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);
    // Create the y-axis
    chart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Points");
    // Paint the ideal line
    chart.append("path")
      .datum(ideal)
      .attr("class", "line ideal")
      .attr("d", idealLine);
    var counter = 0;
    // Paint the actual line
    chart.append("path")
      .datum(actual)
      .attr("class", function(d, i) {
        return 'line ' + d[i].class;
      })
      .attr("d", actualLine);

    var redLines = chart.selectAll(null)
      .data(actual.filter(function(d) {
        return d.added
      }))
      .enter()
      .append("line")
      .attr("x1", function(d) {
        return x(d.date)
      })
      .attr("x2", function(d) {
        return x(d.date)
      })
      .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return y(d.points)
      })
      .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return y(d.points - d.added)
      })
      .style("stroke", "red")
      .style("stroke-width", 4);
  </script>
</body>
```